# problem with receiving emails with Django

Tags: django, email, django-views

i have a simple contact Page in my Django App that receive emails when user submit the form
but when i check my Gmail it shows that i received email from my email, like i sent email from my email to myself

Here is my views.py:

```
def Contact(request):
form=ContactForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    email=form.cleaned_data["email"]
    subject=form.cleaned_data["subject"]
    message=form.cleaned_data["message"]
    send_mail(
        subject,
        message,
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        [email],
        fail_silently=False,
)
    messages.success(request,"your message has been sent successfully")
context={"form":form}
return render(request,"contact.html",context)
```

and here is my settings.py:

```html
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '**********'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*********'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL= False
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
```

but when i check my Gmail it shows that i received email from my email, like i sent email from my email to myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the signature of the `send_mail` function:

```py
send_mail(
    subject,
    message,
    from_email,
    recipient_list,
    fail_silently=False,
    auth_user=None,
    auth_password=None,
    connection=None,
    html_message=None
)
```

You're passing `settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER` to the `from_email` parameter. So I'm guessing the value of `settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER` is your gmail account.

Comment: I'm glad! Please mark my answer as correct if you're pleased with the solution!